# how to show share bottomsheet in ionic for file sharing?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic project where i am working on a share button so when i click the share button a bottom sheet with the following functionality will show

[image]

so is there any plugin or something to achieve this functionality. Thanks

Comment: Its normal, use actionsheet, and inside action sheet put slides and inaide slides put grid and set the ion-col size 4, and pit these cols inside ion row, and by this way you can set the items to be shared manually, and use social  share for each item like share with sms and share with whatsapp,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this awesome native plugin:

[Social Sharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing)

and read the docs here:

[Docs on Github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

I used it. it is really good!